# Android MultilevelListView Height of the children sublist

Tags: android, android-layout

Catgory1
-SubCat1.1
  -Item1.1.1
  -Item1.1.2
  -SubCategory1.1.1
   - Item 1.1.1.1
   - Item 1.1.1.2
   - Item 1.1.1.3
-SubCat1.2
 and so on....

The problem is while the SubCat1.1 is again expanded, the height of the list containing children is not adjusted and instead it gets a scrollview.

I want that the below items shift to give room to the expandable list of the sub category.

Comment: Finally used Customized listview and inflated sub items at runtime and notifyDataStateChanged() with recycleradapter to achieve this.